# Add a trailing slash while building URLs from Helpers in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, view-helpers, trailing-slash

I'm working on a blog-like website in CakePHP 3 and made the canonical URL structure with a trailing slash for SEO purposes. To accomplish this, in the routes file I built the requests to match a trailing slash, and in the `webroot` `.htaccess` made the proper redirects to handle requests without a trailing slash. Also, in the  `AppController` I override the redirect function to manage redirects from Controllers:

```
function redirect($url, $status = null, $exit = true)
{
    $routerUrl = Router::url($url, true);
    if(!preg_match('/\.[a-z0-9]{1,5}$/', strtolower($routerUrl)) && substr($routerUrl, -1) != '/') {
        $routerUrl .= '/';
    }
    parent::redirect($routerUrl, $status, $exit);
}
```

So far, so good.

Now, I would like to build URLs with a trailing slash every time I build them with a Helper, like `FormHelper` or `HtmlHelper`. For example:

```
$this->Form->create(null, [
    'url' => ['controller' => 'Messages', 'action' => 'send']
]);
```

The URL output in this case would be:

**/messages/send**

And I need it to be:

**/messages/send/**

At the moment I'm hard-coding the URL in the Helper's options for it to work (not in production yet). If I use the example's option, when the Form is submitted it redirects **/messages/send** to **/messages/send/** because of the `.htaccess` redirect rules and the POST data is lost.

Thanks in advance, and I apologize for my poor English, I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: Just don't do it, whether you use URLs with or without trailing slash [**has no effect on SEO**](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2010/04/to-slash-or-not-to-slash.html), just make sure that you consistently stick with one or the other.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. Probably I didn't express myself properly. When I say "for SEO purposes", I mean that I would like to stick with the trailing slash URL structure, not that the trailing slash itself would help my SEO.

Comment: I agree with @ndm - but see https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-trailing-slash

Comment: @mark thank you for advise and your refference. I have found that code before asking the question. I tried to use it but it was kind of troublesome as it is meant to be used in CakePHP 2.x. In fact, all the code and workarounds I found regarding this "issue" were meant for CakePHP 2.x. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’d recommend to [create an alias](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers.html#aliasing-helpers) for your `Helper` and tweak the URL building.

**src/View/AppView.php**

```
class AppView extends View
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        $this->loadHelper('Url', [
            'className' => 'MyUrl'
        ]);
    }
}
```

**src/View/Helper/MyUrlHelper.php**

```
namespace App\View\Helper;

use Cake\View\Helper\UrlHelper;

class MyUrlHelper extends HtmlHelper
{
    public function build($url = null, $options = false)
    {
        // Add your code to override the core UrlHelper build() function

        return $url;
    }
}
```

Find the original source of `UrlHelper` [here](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/source-class-Cake.View.Helper.UrlHelper.html#23-288).

Comment: Thank you very much! That was exactly what I needed. I had to change `MyUrlHelper.php` a little bit for it to work: I added `use Cake\Routing\Router` and extended `MyUrlHelper` from `UrlHelper` instead of extending from `HtmlHelper`. Thanks again! This is a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a `/` at the end of the action, you could try it:

```
$this->Form->create(null, [
    'url' => $this->Url->build('/Messages/send/', true)
]);
```

**See also**

- [Setting a URL for the Form](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/form.html#setting-a-url-for-the-form)
- [Generating URLs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/url.html#generating-urls)

Comment: I already have the URL like that for it to work, but what I need is to craft the URL with the trailing slash using the Controller and Action option.
['controller' => 'Messages', 'action' => 'send']
I would like to do this in order to avoid tracking down each URL set through this method in case I decide to change the request alias in the future

Answer (score 0):

I SOLVED it by three characters :) ...

1- open \vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\View\Helper\UrlHelper.php
2- go to build function and add .'/' to the return $url like below

it should look likes
**return $url.'/';**

instead of
**return $url;**

I know it's dirty solution  and not good to edit core ... I think you'd better overwrite build function...

I hope there is better way

Comment: I'm sorry this will break the image ... but I put it in ..... 
\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\View\Helper\HtmlHelper.php -> link function ... it works fine